# How to store data in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have written a program which accepts data and then displays it in a table form like ths-

def table(x):

```
  print("|         NAME           | SCORE  |   STATUS    |  DATE STARTED   |    DATE ENDED    |")


  for KI in x:
  print("|",KI[0]," "*(21-len(KI[0])),"|"," ",KI[1]," ","|",KI[2]," "*(10-len(KI[2])),"|"," "*2,KI[3]," ","|"," "*3,KI[4]," ","|")
```

By storing the data entered as a list I am able to create a table but I want to save this list in such a way that I can keep adding data to it and this data doesn't get erased when the program ends.How do I do this? .

Comment: How about to write data in a file and adding data to that file? After program ends, you are going to have all stored.

Comment: Store it in a database is another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to store the value into a file. You can do something like this:

```py
file = open('myfile.txt','w')                # 'w' to write and 'a' to append in future
file.write(**put details here**) 
file.close()
```